# No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}UpdateXXXRequest]

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I upgraded an old application which exposes 6 different SOAP web services with different namespaces. Everything seems working correctly when we use endpoints taken through its generated wsdl.

here is a sample request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:pres="http://MY_NAMESPACE.com">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pres:UpdateXXXRequest>
      </pres:UpdateXXXRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Envelope>
```

but there are some clients which send request in following format

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:pres="http://MY_NAMESPACE.com">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <q0:UpdateXXXRequest xmlns:q0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      </q0:UpdateXXXRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Envelope
```

this request couses error **No Endpoint Found** due to the namespace **xmlns:q0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"** used with payload UpdateXXXRequest.

According to my analysis, Spring framework uses **EndpointMapping** to identify the respective method and then makes a call to the service based on namespace (either given with body payload **q0:UpdateXXXRequest xmlns:q0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"** or from soapenv:Envelop)

In case of **{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}UpdateRxFillRequest** it its failed because method is defined with its own namespace and spring only looks for namespace defined with method through @Payload annotation.

if it remove q0 from UpdateXXXRequest or use the actual namespace it works fine but clients are sending the request with **http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/**

What can be the way to support **http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/** & **http://MY_NAMESPACE.com** for each method.

although I have 100+ endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix the issue by replacing @Payload annotation on SOAP method with @Payloads which allows to add multiple @Payload annotations. I added two one with service namespace as **http://MY_NAMESPACE.com** and second with **http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/**.
And spring framework recognized the SOAP endpoint with both annotations.