# No endpoint mapping found for `[SaajSoapMessage {http://api.com}getCountryRequest]`

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, soap

I try to make a Web service using JAVA and SOAP, but every time I try to run the application, I get the following error: `No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://api.com}getCountryRequest]`.

I have been attempting to expose listed endpoints like mentioned on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919343/11973623), but has no effect. Furthermore, I also attempted to add the following code to the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.webservices.expose-all-endpoints=true
```

But it doesn't work. Then I set out to add another code to the `application.properties` file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=env,beans
```

But that didn't work either. I have tried many ways to solve this problem for a long time, but I can't find a solution. I will be genuinely grateful if you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Note: To re-create the issue, here is [my repo](https://github.com/Rusydy/producing-web-service)

Comment: What endpoints are you trying to expose? What is it you are trying to achieve that is totally unclear to me? You are messing around with Spring WebServices endpoints and next move to Spring Boot actuator endpoints? I don't see the relation nor get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to create an API using SOAP and Java, but I not sure why I get this error. I have been trying lots of way but still can make any request to my WSDL service.

Comment: You don't need anything af the properties, normally, you added, so ditch them. I quickly looked at your configuration and that disables auto-configuration. Remove the `@EnableWs` and the `MessageDispatcherServlet` those are added automatically. Add `spring.webservices.path=/ws`, remove the `location` from the wsdl definition and your `targetNamespace` seems to be wrong as well (it is `http://api.com` not what you have.

Comment: I've been removing `@EnableWs` and `MessageDispatcherServle` but still have the same issue, am I doing it right? Here is [my changes](https://github.com/Rusydy/producing-web-service/pull/1/files)

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: I use IntelliJ and run it like [this](https://ibb.co/mGTxjZY) then hit it using insomnia like [this](https://ibb.co/tBG5mKK)

Comment: Please include it in your question instead of adding links to some offsite resources.

Comment: It's too long for `comment` so I used images yesterday. 
So, I use IntelliJ to run the program and hit `http://localhost:8080/ws/`

Comment: with [payload](https://github.com/Rusydy/producing-web-service/blob/c68fcc6c3315264a510979885aeda16ef5dc2fcc/src/main/resources/coutry-req.xml) in insomnia

Comment: I also make sure I set Content-Type = text/xml on header

Comment: Again please edit your question, don't post additional information as comments as that is unreadable. That being said the namespace in your endpoint is wrong. It should match the one in the XSD, it doesn't so doesn't find the mapping.

Comment: Yes, I miss `NAME_SPACE_URI` on `CountryEndpoint` class, now I have 500 error code and that's progress for this week, thank you very much.
```xml
<faultstring xml:lang="en">No adapter for endpoint [public com.api.GetCountryResponse com.api.producingwebservice.CountryEndpoint.getCountry(com.api.GetCountryRequest)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring>
```